# error modulo mercadopago en prestashop 1.7

Tags: mercadopago, prestashop

Instale el modulo de mercadopago en prestashop 1.7 sin errores (estoy usando la modalidad checkout básico) y al presionar el botón de pagar me da el siguiente error
Me podrían ayudar por favor 
Gracias

```
ContextErrorException in standard.php line 94:
Notice: Undefined index: init_point
in standard.php line 94
at ErrorHandler->handleError('8', 'Undefined index: init_point', '/home/c0560427/public_html/prestashop/modules/mercadopago/controllers/front/standard.php', '94', array('data' => array('preferences_url' => null), 'cart' => object(Cart), 'authorized' => true, 'module' => array('id_module' => '54', 'id_hook' => '145', 'name' => 'mercadopago', 'position' => '4'), 'messageLog' => 'MercadoPago - post parameters : Array ( [external_reference] => 10 [items] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 8 [title] => prueba [description] => [quantity] => 1 [unit_price] => 1.21 [picture_url] => urlmisitio/prestashop/24/prueba.jpg [category_id] => others ) ) [shipments] => Array ( ) [sponsor_id] => 187899872 [auto_return] => approved [back_urls] => Array ( [success] => urlmisitio/es/module/mercadopago/validationstandard?checkout=standard&cart_id=10&typeReturn=success [failure] => urlmisitio/prestashop/es/module/mercadopago/validationstandard?checkout=standard&cart_id=10&typeReturn=failure [pending] => urlmisitio/prestashop/es/module/mercadopago/validationstandard?checkout=standard&cart_id=10&typeReturn=pending ) [payment_methods] => Array ( [excluded_payment_methods] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => visa ) [1] => Array ( [id] => master ) [2] => Array ( [id] => amex ) [3] => Array ( [id] => naranja ) [4] => Array ( [id] => nativa ) [5] => Array ( [id] => tarshop ) [6] => Array ( [id] => cencosud ) [7] => Array ( [id] => cabal ) [8] => Array ( [id] => argencard ) [9] => Array ( [id] => diners ) [10] => Array ( [id] => pagofacil ) [11] => Array ( [id] => rapipago ) [12] => Array ( [id] => redlink ) [13] => Array ( [id] => bapropagos ) [14] => Array ( [id] => cmr ) [15] => Array ( [id] => cordial ) [16] => Array ( [id] => cordobesa ) [17] => Array ( [id] => maestro ) [18] => Array ( [id] => debvisa ) [19] => Array ( [id] => debcabal ) [20] => Array ( [id] => debmaster ) [21] => Array ( [id] => cargavirtual ) ) [excluded_payment_types] => Array ( ) [installments] => 1 ) [notification_url] urlmisitio/prestashop/es/module/mercadopago/standardreturn?checkout=standard&cart_id=10 [payer] => Array ( [first_name] => Pablo [last_name] => Pellegrinet [email] => pablo.pellegrinet@gmail.com [phone] => Array ( [area_code] => - [number] => 156379551| ) [address] => Array ( [zip_code] => N5000ggg [street_name] => Galeotti 1336 - - Cordoba/Argentina [street_number] => - ) [identification] => Array ( [number] => [type] => ) [name] => Pablo [surname] => Pellegrinet ) ) ', 'postParameters' => array('external_reference' => '10', 'items' => array(array('id' => '8', 'title' => 'prueba', 'description' => '', 'quantity' => '1', 'unit_price' => '1.21', 'picture_url' => 'urlmisitio/prestashop/24/prueba.jpg', 'category_id' => 'others')), 'shipments' => array(), 'sponsor_id' => '187899872', 'auto_return' => 'approved', 'back_urls' => array('success' => 'urlmisitio/prestashop/es/module/mercadopago/validationstandard?checkout=standard&cart_id=10&typeReturn=success', 'failure' => 'urlmisitio/prestashop/es/module/mercadopago/validationstandard?checkout=standard&cart_id=10&typeReturn=failure', 'pending' => 'urlmisitio/prestashop/es/module/mercadopago/validationstandard?checkout=standard&cart_id=10&typeReturn=pending'), 'payment_methods' => array('excluded_payment_methods' => array(array('id' => 'visa'), array('id' => 'master'), array('id' => 'amex'), array('id' => 'naranja'), array('id' => 'nativa'), array('id' => 'tarshop'), array('id' => 'cencosud'), array('id' => 'cabal'), array('id' => 'argencard'), array('id' => 'diners'), array('id' => 'pagofacil'), array('id' => 'rapipago'), array('id' => 'redlink'), array('id' => 'bapropagos'), array('id' => 'cmr'), array('id' => 'cordial'), array('id' => 'cordobesa'), array('id' => 'maestro'), array('id' => 'debvisa'), array('id' => 'debcabal'), array('id' => 'debmaster'), array('id' => 'cargavirtual')), 'excluded_payment_types' => array(), 'installments' => '1'), 'notification_url' => 'urlmisitio/prestashop/es/module/mercadopago/standardreturn?checkout=standard&cart_id=10', 'payer' => array('first_name' => 'Pablo', 'last_name' => 'Pellegrinet', 'email' => 'mimail@gmail.com', 'phone' => array('area_code' => '-', 'number' => '15555551|'), 'address' => array('zip_code' => 'N5000ggg', 'street_name' => 'micalle 1336 - - Cordoba/Argentina', 'street_number' => '-'), 'identification' => array('number' => '', 'type' => ''), 'name' => 'Pablo', 'surname' => 'P')), 'result' => array('status' => '400', 'response' => array('message' => 'cannot exclude all payments methods', 'error' => 'invalid_payment_methods', 'status' => '400', 'cause' => array())))) in standard.php line 94
at MercadoPagoStandardModuleFrontController->postProcess() in Controller.php line 194
at ControllerCore->run() in Dispatcher.php line 369
at DispatcherCore->dispatch() in index.php line 28
```

Comment: Hola Pablo, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. Esta comunidad de programadores no se especializa en Mercado Pago o Prestashop por lo que tendrás que aportar más elementos que permitan ayudarte. Lo primero es que te asegures que tu pregunta cumple con esta guía __[ask]__. En segundo lugar, haz lo posible para incluir un __[mcve]__. Usa los botones de formato que te ofrece el editor y limita el error a la parte más relevante de tu problema.

Comment: Este curso te será de utilidad: https://www.acamica.com/cursos/105/la-api-mercadolibre-conceptos-finales y este otro también! https://www.acamica.com/cursos/62/introduccion-a-la-api-de-mercadolibre Saludos :D

Answer (score -1):

Hay una explicación de un nuevo modulo de mercado pago para prestashop 1.7 y en el video se explica estos detalles e inclusive muestra el ejemplo con una tienda de prueba en 1.7.6.1.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bCXfcef2NTE

Veo que también deja su contacto para que hagas tu preguntas.

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede resolver la duda el aportar solo con links se considera de baja calidad, por favor lee [answer]